# Websphere application - OS security

Tags: java, windows, file-io, operating-system, websphere-8

I have a Websphere application that creates/modfies/deletes files as part of the business process.

Now it has to be able to copy files over to a different, archive server. How can I give the Websphere process on Server1 access to Server2/myArchiveDir?

Is there a userId that is associated with Websphere?

(We are on a Windows machine.)

Comment: Can you not remotely mount/attach the other server's drive/filesystem?

Comment: what userId do I use to give websphere access to that dir?

Comment: What I'm suggesting would have nothing to do with WebSphere, per se. It would be Windows directory sharing and attaching, with whatever Windows user credentials required.

Answer (score 0):

you need one side to be a server and the other to be a client.

Server Connection:

```
ServerSocket servSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket connect = servSocket.accept();
File file = new File(location);
FileWriter write = new FileWriter(file);
write.write(connect.getInputStream());
file.close();
write.close();
connection.close();
```

Client Side:

```
File transferFile = new File(file);
InputStream in = new InputStream(transferFile);
// Create connection
Socket conn = new Socket(address, port);

OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
copyStream(in,out);

in.close();
out.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: You really only need to know the where the files are located and store them in a list/array/ArrayList/ect and have a program in the background that looks at the directory and iterates through files with isFile() and check the elements for changes or updates all files this way every blah. It can also be used for more then just WebSphere.

Comment: This looks like I need two Websphere servers. The destination server is just a file server with lots of files, can't I push the file directly there?